# MySQL table formatting

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table with about 4 million rows. It has 2 columns which are user-id and property. The user id repeats itself, however has distinct properties. 
I want to create a new table where the user IDs are unique and under the property column, the properties related to that user id are written separated my comma. 
I attempted doing this with php however failed because the time taken was alot. 
Any suggestions on how I could go on to tackle this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows all **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
select user_id,
 group_concat(property) as property
  from your_table
group by user_id
```

If you want to update your current table with this resultset, then use this resultset to store data in a different temporary table. Then truncate your table and restore data from this temporary table. But make sure to take backup of current data before doing it.